# testng plugin installed on scalaIDE(eclipse) goes away after the system restarts

Tags: eclipse, testng, scala-ide, testng-eclipse

I have [scalaIDE](http://scala-ide.org/) installed on my macOS.
Also I have installed [TestNG](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/testng-eclipse?mpc=true&mpc_state=) plugin using market place.

When I shutdown my system and restart next day, I don't see TestNG features and I have to re-intsall again.

What might be the cause and how can I fix it permanently.